# Issue by using Gson (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, gson, emulation

I'm new in Android and I was following a tutorial about how to use Gson. 
(http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

I have tried to receive the following json object.
(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk)

This is my code:

MainClass:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
    Weather weather = gson.fromJson(reader, Weather.class);
    Toast.makeText(this, weather.clouds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {

      HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
      final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
        "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
       return null;
      }

      HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
      return getResponseEntity.getContent();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      getRequest.abort();
      Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }

    return null;

}}
```

WeatherClass:

```
public class Weather {

public double lon;

public double lat;

public String country;

public int speed;

@SerializedName("all")
public int clouds;
}
```

If I run this on the emulator, my App "unfortunately has stopped" and LogCat say this:

[image]

[image]

I found much about gson problems on stackoverflow but nothing solved my problem.
So what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: You are creating/initiating internet request in mainThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  are performing network operation inside main thread. You shouldn't do that because you can block your UI ths way. Android warns you about it and throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Perform network operation on worker thread. You can use `AsyncTask` for that if you would like to use results of your network operation to update UI. If you do not need to update your UI simply create a new thread and do network stuff there.

Comment: I tried it asynchron and it works fine, thanks !!!

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Please vote up the asnwer also if you don't mind.